# C# ,Getting one value out of repetitive records of a column

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have `Emp_id`, `name` , and `payment_date` columns in `payment` table, in this table there will be a repetitive value of `Emp_id` and `name` with diffrent `payment_date` so. when I want to get list of employee name those didn't pay their payment in the given payment date the result is repetitive that compares only payment date. and I get repetitive `emp_id` and `name`. but I want to get only employee name, and `emp_id` once without repeating.

```cs
List<string> empIds = 
    db.UnRegistrations.Select(e => e.emp_Id).ToList();
    
foreach (string cbeId in cbeIds) 
{
    var unpaid = db.UnContributions
        .Where(td => td.Payment_month != date && td.Emp_Id == empIds)
        .GroupBy(td => new { td.emp_Id, td.Payment_month })
        .Select(group => group.First())
        .ToList()

    unpaidContributions.AddRange(unpaid);
}
```

Comment: What is your `cbeIds` value? From your code, seems you keep looping to execute the query and add the result into the list but the `cbeId` isn't used (Need to know the purpose of this `cbeIds` foreach loop). And try to show us some sample data. Thanks.

Comment: Need more than one example of the input strings.  Depending on the type of data then method to parse will be different.

Comment: Thank you a lot . I fix it. using 
var unpaid = db.UnContributions.Where(td => td.Payment_month != date && td.emp_Id == cbeId)
                                .GroupBy(td => new { td.emp_Id })
                                .Select(group => group.First())
                                .ToList();

                            unpaidContributions.AddRange(unpaid);

Comment: Just use `Distinct` it will generate more effective query.